# How can control my brightness of the display on hp nseries laptop

Tags: 12.04, brightness, backlight

I just bought a new laptop and i have installed windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 on it. 
And while using ubuntu i am not able to control my brightness with the dedicated keys or the softwares such as brightness controller and brightness indicator.

I have also tried to search the brightness directory with the command
grep . /sys/class/backlight/*

and this is showing no such file or directory error.

So what should i do now..

I have also tried making changes in the grub file.

i have added acpi_backlight=vendor in the grub cmdline default line...

Please help my laptop is working in max brightness and its difficult to work...

Answer (score 0):

you can install xbacklight by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight -y
```

then Go System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts

Add followings :

```
Brightness Down = xbacklight -10
Brightness Up = xbacklight +10
```

then click on "Disabled" and press your preferred combinations keys (for ex. CTRL+F2 and CTRL+F3)

Comment: But it is not working..:( I think maybe i need to install some drivers or something. ??

Comment: Have you updated your grub after changing those modifications ?

Comment: if it doesn't work, you should just upgrade to 13.10 . it'll work definitely

Comment: Yeah i have updated my grub after making those modifications but its still not working..

Comment: @Tejvir Upgrade ubuntu to 13.10 !!!

Comment: Yeah maybe that's the only option left... I'll trying upgrading to 13.10.. :)